# Ubuntu 15.04 - cannot enable additional drivers

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom

I've just installed Ubuntu 15.04 on my hd.

When I try to enable the Broadcom 802.11 wireless driver from Software & Updates, Additional Drivers, the dialog just refreshes itself and tells me that no additional drivers are in use.

```
$ lspci -nn | grep 0280
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
```

From the live-cd it worked ok, but from the hard drive installation it seems like the changes are not being taken into account.

Anybody else had the same issue?

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless device from the terminal: `lspci -nn | grep 0280`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I have installed Ubuntu without an enternet connection and I can't get this driver installed. I just reinstall Ubuntu from the CD **with a wired connection**. I'm sure that this is a new bug with this new Ubuntu version.

Comment: after connecting with the wired connection you could install the wireless driver and then work without the wire?

Comment: I connect the wired during the installation process. So this install all additional drivers. Even if I connect after the first installation, this doesn't help.